# How to stop Microsoft Word from accepting American spellings?

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check

I am writing something for people in the UK, and I have switched the language of Microsoft word to *English (UK)*, but when I write something like “program” or “math” or “realize”, the spell checker doesn't mark it wrong.

How to make Word reject all American spellings?

Comment: Part of the problem is that whilst those are not the often-preferred spellings in UK English, none of them are actually **wrong**. Program is the preferred form when discussing things that run on computers, vs things shown on TV. Realize is an older spelling variant of realise & the OED recognises both. Math is the odd one out but a spell-checker would think of it as a singular form of maths, even if a human wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem comes from the fact that the *Microsoft* *Word* Word-Processor did not really switch to the English (U.K.) Language.

Even if it did, for some reason it has reverted back to the English (U.S.) Language and this is why it is not disturbed by the American Spellings.

Switching Languages can be tricky. In order to fix your Issue, just select all of the Text that you want to have in your English (U.K.) Language or even the whole of the Document using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ShortCut Key Combination. Then, reapply the Language Properties to the Whole Selection toward the English (U.K.) Language.

This might also come from the Erroneous AutoDetection of the Proofing Language.